# algorithm for color picker with radius (blur?)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, canvas

I'd like to sample a color from a particular point on a canvas. Instead of just one pixel's color:

```
context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
```

I'd like to sample colors from pixels around this point. I'm imagining that something like [Quasimondo's StackBlur](http://quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html) would be an appropriate algorithm for calculating the average color around a point by a certain radius. Is a blur algorithm the right way to go? Does any particular blur algorithm have advantages over other ones for this use?

An objective answer will compare arithmetic average of surrounding pixels with a blurred image or weighted average.

Comment: why a blur, why not take the (arithmetic) average colour?

Comment: That's part of the question :-) Seems like closer pixels should weigh more in the average, so (to my visual brain) that looks like a blur.

Comment: suppose you have found a blur algorithm that you want to use. and you blurred the area that you want to use to pick the color. how do you actually compute the color after that?

Comment: Adobe Photoshop's eyedropper uses an average color in sample of selected size (point, 3x3, 5x5, 11x11, 31x31, 51x51 and 101x101).

Comment: @akonsu once the image is blurred by the radius, then it's the same code as above: `getImageData` for one pixel.

@MaxZuber thanks for that. So that would be a square around the point, and all pixels evenly averaged?

Comment: one idea might be to build a color histogram of the colors found in the area and find the peak. if it has more than one peak, smooth it until it has one peak.

Comment: I'd like it to be simple and fast. Thinking I'll experiment with a weighted average of a square around the pixel.

Comment: I could be cheeky and summon @Quasimondo for a blur-expert opinion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blur is technically average but it will will find the average *per pixel* in the area it scans. This is overcomplicated when you just want the average color for the whole area, not per pixel. Using blur means poor performance compared to a linear scan to find the average, which is what you need for finding the average color for the area.

What you want is a plain average of all pixels in the area, in sum. A process for that would be like:

- Define the picker radius
- Calculate length (radius x radius)
- Define a square region which the circle fit into
- Traverse each line, for each point do:

  - Calculate distance from current x,y to center
  - Determine if it is inside the precalculated length
  - If not skip, if yes, store the pixel to an array
- Count number of pixels, add them up and divide on count => average pixel for that circle

To calculate distance from (x,y) to center:

```
var length = radius * radius;          // max distance from center
var diffX = Math.abs(x - centerX); 
var diffY = Math.abs(y - centerY);
var dist = diffX*diffX + diffY*diffY;  // distance center -> x,y

if (dist <= length) { ...add sample to array... }

// ...
// do average: sum of all r, sum of all g etc.. 
// r divided on number of entries in array, etc. (round of values)
```

(tip: you don't need to square the distances in this case)

```js
// vars and load some image
var vcanvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    vctx = vcanvas.getContext("2d"),
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    w = 500, h = 300,
    img = new Image();
    
img.crossOrigin = "";
img.onload = prep;
img.src = "//i.imgur.com/SetDGOB.jpg";

// setup and prepare image for canvases
function prep() {
  vcanvas.width = canvas.width = w;
  vcanvas.height = canvas.height = h;
  
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);  // draw in off-screen canvas
  vcanvas.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + canvas.toDataURL() + ")";  // set as bg to visual canvas
  vctx.font = "16px sans-serif";   // to draw values to screen
  vctx.lineWidth = 8;              // lupe ring width
  
  // sample image on mouse move
  vcanvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var rect = vcanvas.getBoundingClientRect(),  // correct mouse pos.
        x = e.clientX - rect.left,
        y = e.clientY - rect.top,
        radius = 6,                              // sample radius
        zoom = 4,                                // zoom (for visuals only)
        sx = (w * zoom - w) / w,                 // calc scale factors
        sy = (h * zoom - h) / h,
        avg = sample(x, y, radius);              // sample area (average)
    
    // draw zoomed circle
    vctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    if (null == avg) return;                     // nothing to show
    
    vctx.beginPath();
    vctx.arc(x, y, radius * zoom, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    vctx.fill();
    
    //vctx.scale(zoom, zoom);
    vctx.translate(-x * sx, -y * sy);
    vctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
    vctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, w*zoom, h*zoom);
    vctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    vctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";

    // draw black ring
    vctx.beginPath();
    vctx.arc(x, y, radius * zoom + vctx.lineWidth * 0.5, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    vctx.strokeStyle = "#555";
    vctx.closePath();
    vctx.stroke();
    
    // draw average color ring
    vctx.beginPath();
    vctx.arc(x, y, radius * zoom + vctx.lineWidth * 0.5 + 1, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    vctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(" + avg.r + "," + avg.g + "," + avg.b + ")";
    vctx.closePath();
    vctx.stroke();

    vctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    vctx.fillText("x:" + x + " y:" + y + " " + vctx.strokeStyle, 12, 22);

    vctx.fillStyle = "#0f0";
    vctx.fillText("x:" + x + " y:" + y + " " + vctx.strokeStyle, 10, 20);

  }
}

// This will do the color sampling from the circle
function sample(cx, cy, radius) {
  var r = 0, g = 0, b = 0, a = 0, cnt = 0,  // initialize
      length = radius * radius,             // calc max distance from center
      region,                               // region with pixels to sample
      idata, buffer, len,                   // data buffers
      i, p, x, y, dx, dy, dist;
  
  // calc region:
  region = {
    x: cx - radius,
    y: cy - radius,
    w: Math.min(w-cx+radius, radius*2)|0,
    h: Math.min(h-cy+radius, radius*2)|0
  };

  // check and adjust region to fit inside canvas area
  if (region.x < 0) {region.w + region.x; region.x = 0}
  if (region.y < 0) {region.h + region.y; region.y = 0}
  if (region.w < 1 || region.h < 1 ) return null;
  
  // get buffer for region
  idata = ctx.getImageData(region.x|0, region.y|0, region.w|0, region.h|0);
  buffer = idata.data;
  len = buffer.length;
  
  // iterate region and sample pixels with circle
  for(y = 0; y < region.h; y++) {
    for(x = 0; x < region.w; x++) {
      dx = radius - x;
      dy = radius - y;
      dist = Math.abs(dx*dx + dy*dy); // dist. from center to current x,y in buffer
      
      // add value if within circle
      if (dist <= length) {
        p = (y * region.h + x)*4;
        r += buffer[p];
        g += buffer[p+1];
        b += buffer[p+2];
        a += buffer[p+3];
        cnt++;
      }
    }
  }
  
  // no samples? (should never happen!)
  if (!cnt) return null;
  
  // calculate and return average
  return {
    r: (r / cnt + 0.5)|0,
    g: (g / cnt + 0.5)|0,
    b: (b / cnt + 0.5)|0,
    a: (a / cnt + 0.5)|0
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {cursor:crosshair}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

(There are ways to optmize this code by storing the buffer for the whole image instead of an off-screen canvas, get the region based on offsets etc., but I kept it this way for simplicity (?) ...).

Comment: Does anybody know if Photoshop's color picker averages the circle or square of pixels?

Comment: Is there a disadvantage to weighing the average by distance? Why is the plain average preferable?

Comment: @forresto I believe PS uses square regions. The distance does not affect the result (it's not use as a weight, just to limit the area), only the area the pixels are retrieved from. You will here get an average of pixels inside the circle. Plain average is what you want to get the average of the pixel values... :) Blur will average current pixel with surrounding pixels - this is essentially a low-pass filter

Comment: Sweet demo! I'm still not 100% on the disadvantage of the blur / low-pass filter issue, other than simple averaging keeps it simpler.

Comment: @forresto and faster, and more correct.. anyways (blur is overcomplicated for this purpose, getting average value of the area - blur gets the average value *per pixel* in the area)